# How to get the height of a button component after card component render in jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to write a test case where height of a Button from PopoverMenu doesn't change regardless of how many headers are created. Before the fix, height of button would stretch out along with number of headers due to the increase in height. So I made a fix and tryin to add test case to prove it, but I'm always getting 0 for `buttonHeightWithOneHeader`. `getButton()` selects the button element and trying to get the height of that button by using `getBoundingClientRect().height`, but no luck. Doesn't `await waitFor` give enough time for Card component to finish render? Not sure why I can't get the height of Button element.

```
let buttonHeightWithOneHeader = 0;
let buttonHeightWithSixHeaders = 0;
  it('should have its button height remain unchanged regardless of the height of the header of the card', async () => {
    const { rerender } = render(
      <Card>
        <Card.Content>
          <Card.Header
            title="Overwatch"
            description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed dos eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
            action={
              <PopoverMenu
                buttonLabel="Menu"
                testId="button-menu"
              >
              </PopoverMenu>
            }
          />
        </Card.Content>
      </Card>
    );
    await waitFor(() => {
      buttonHeightWithOneHeader = getButton().getBoundingClientRect().height;
    });
  
    rerender(
      <Card>
        <Card.Content>
          <Card.Header
            title="Overwatch Overwatch Overwatch Overwatch Overwatch Overwatch"
            description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed dos eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
            action={
              <PopoverMenu
                buttonLabel="Menu"
                testId="button-menu"
              >
              </PopoverMenu>
            }
          />
        </Card.Content>
      </Card>
    );
    await waitFor(() => {
      buttonHeightWithSixHeaders = getButton().getBoundingClientRect().height;
    });

    expect(buttonHeightWithOneHeader).toEqual(buttonHeightWithSixHeaders );
  });
```